# Is there a faster way to compare two sqlite3 tables in python?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to compare two tables in an sqlite3 database in python. One of the answers to this question:

[Comparing two sqlite3 tables using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227567/comparing-two-sqlite3-tables-using-python)

gives a solution:

> Alternatively, import them into SQLite tables. Then you can use queries like the following:
>
> `SELECT * FROM a INTERSECT SELECT * FROM b;`
>
> `SELECT * FROM a EXCEPT    SELECT * FROM b;`
>
> to get rows that exist in both tables, or only in one table.

This works great for tables with less than a million rows, but is far too slow for my program which requires comparing tables with more than ten billion rows. (Script took over ten minutes for just 100 million rows.)

**Is there a faster way to compare two sqlite3 tables in python?**

I thought about trying to compare the hashes of the two database files, but an overview of a program called [dbhash on sqlite.org](https://sqlite.org/dbhash.html) claims that even if the contents of two database files are the same certain operations "can potentially cause vast changes to the raw database file, and hence cause very different SHA1 hashes at the file level," which makes me think that this would not work unless I ran some sort of script to query all the data in an ordered fashion and then hash that (like the dbhash program does), but would that even be faster?

Or should I be using another database entirely that can preform this comparison faster than sqlite3?

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: There have been some good ideas put forward so far, but to clarify: the order of the tables doesn't matter, just the contents.

Comment: Minus possibly the time needed to load the data into your SQLite database, I would expect the comparisons you need to run much faster in a database than in Python code.

Comment: Could you inform why do you need that? If you want to synchronize the dbs take a look at [litesync](http://litesync.io) or [litereplica](http://litereplica.io). They are way faster.

Comment: @BernardoRamos Yes, I am essentially trying to synchronize information among multiple different nodes, so this looks promising, thanks.

Comment: Does *your* database have primary keys? That would allow much more efficient lookups.

Comment: @CL.Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resort to the following workaround:

1. Add a column to each table where you store a hash over the content of all other columns.
2. Add an index to the new column.
3. Compute and store the hash with the record.
4. Compare the hash columns of your tables instead of using `intersect`/`except`.

If altering the tables isn't an option you can perhaps create new tables that relate a hash to the primary key or rowid of the hashed record.

With that you shift part of the processing time needed for the comparison to the time you insert/update the records. I would expect this to be significant faster at the time you execute the comparison than comparing all columns of all rows just then.

Of course your hash must be aware of the order of values and produce unique values for every permutation; a simple checksum won't suffice. Suggestion:

1. Convert every column value to a string.
2. Concatenate the strings with a separator that's guaranteed not to occur in the values themselves.
3. Use SHA1 or a similarly sophisticated hashing algorithm over the concatenated string.

You can test whether storing the hash as string, blob or integer (provided it fits into 64 bit) makes a difference in speed.

Comment: @nellapizza I would be interested in some (rough) benchmark results and details: what's the speedup factor, and what did you actually do (differently)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will take a lot of time for a single thread (or even several) on a single hard drive to crawl billions of raws.

It can obviously be better with stronger DB engines but indexing all your columns would not really help in the end.

You have to resort to precalculation or distributing your dataset amongst multiple systems...

If you have a LOT of RAM you can try copying the SQLite files first in `/dev/shm` allowing you to read your data straight from memory and benefit a performance boost.